# Using assignment operator in the parameter of a function call

Tags: c++

I am a beginner at c++ can anyone explain me this code:

```
#include <iostream>

void display(int b)
{
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a;

    display(a=10);//display 10

    std::cout << a << std::endl;//also display 10

    return 0;
}
```

I know we can use = operator to set default values for a function parameters, but here it's in the function call, apparently "disply(a=10)" pass the value 10 to the function and store it in the variable "a" at the sametime.

is this correct coding in c++ and can anyone explain the assignment part?

Comment: Yes but it's not good practice, because it looks confusing.

Comment: … and might even look like an error. If I see `x=y` inside an `if` or function call, I assume that the author really wanted to do `x==y`.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
display(a=10);//display 10
```

equals to:

```
a = 10;
display(a);
```

This is because the value of the clause `a = 10;` is `a`.

I think this answers your question.

Comment: Not quite. The result of the assignment expression is an lvalue referring the left operand. This matters if `display` takes its parameter by non-const lvalue reference or by rvalue reference.

Comment: But be noted that normally we don't write c++ code like this, as @Neil says.

Comment: @westiti Depends how you define "correct". The compiler is happy, sure, but I certainly won't be if I had to read that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know about `=` operator more. Not only is it assign rhs (right hand side) value to lhs (left hand side), but also it *refers to* the lhs.

Suppose this code:

```
a = b = c;
```

is exactly equal to

```
a = (b = c);
```

because `=` is right-associative.

If `c` is 10, the code assign 10 into b, and assign the value of `b` into a. So now `a == b == c == 10`.

Comment: Thanks editor, I forgot what is *right-associative* in English >o<

Answer (score 1):

The built-in assignment operator `=`

- is *right-associative*
  which means it groups to right, e.g. `a = b = c` means `a = (b = c)`,
- is an *lvalue* expression that refers to the left hand side.

Note that in C an assignment produces a pure *value*, while in C++ it produces a reference (in the common language meaning of referring).

This means that you can assign a value to multiple variables:

```
a = b = c = 12345;
```

which is parsed as

```
a = (b = (c = 12345));
```

which first copies `12345` to `c`, then copies `c` to `b`, then copies `b` to `a`.

And it means that you can assign to the result of an assignment:

```
((a = b) = c) = 12345;
```

which first copies the `b` value to `a`, then copies the `c` value to `a`, then copies `12345` to `a`, leaving `b` and `c` unchanged…

In your case, the code

```
display(a=10);
```

is equivalent to

```
a = 10;  display( a );
```

Since the `display` function takes an `int` by value, this is equivalent to

```
display( 10 )
```

but if `display` had a reference argument then it could not be rewritten this way.

---

A common pitfall is to write

```
if( x = 12345 )
```

when one means to do a comparison,

```
if( x == 12345 )
```

Many compilers will warn about the first if the warning level is upped, as it should be.

More guaranteed ways to detect it include

- Using `const` everywhere it can be used.
  `x` can’t be assigned to when it’s `const`. This is my preferred solution.
- Writing `if( 12345 == x )`.
  Some people prefer this, but I find it hard to read, and as opposed to `const` it only helps to avoid the mis-typing when the writer is already, at that very point, very aware of the problem.
- Defining a custom `if` construct via a macro.
  Technically this works, also for other constructs that use boolean conditions, but in order to be useful such a macro should be short, and this runs the risk of name collision. It's also hard on maintainers who are unfamiliar with the (effectively) custom language.

---

In C++03 the standard library required that any container element type should be *assignable*, and the *assignable* criterion required that a custom assignment operator `T::operator=` should return `T&` (C++03 §23.1/4) – which is also a requirement on the built-in assignment operator.

Until I learned that I used to define assignment operators with result type `void`, since I saw no point in supporting coding of expressions with side-effects (which is generally a bad practice) at the cost of both efficiency and verbosity.

Unfortunately this is a case where in C++ you pay for what you don’t use and generally should not use.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment `<variable> = <value>` in C, C++ is and **expression** which means it have a value and this value is, of course, the `<value>` you've just assigned.

That's the reason why you can assign a value to multiple variables like this:

```
a = b = c = 1;
```

because internally it works something like this

```
a = value of (b = value of (c = 1));
```

and since the assignment does indeed have a value, the value of `(c = 1)` is
`1`, value of `(b = (c = 1))` is `1` and therefore we get `a = 1`. And as a

If the assignment wouldn't be an expression and didn't have a value, we would
get an error, because `value of (c = 1)` would not exist and we would get a
syntax error.

So in your code, `display(a=10);` means: *set value `a` to `10` and pass the
resulting value (which would be 10) as an argument to the function `display`.

Comment: Let's not conflate C and C++ here. The result of an assignment expression is different in the two languages. It's an lvalue in C++, but not in C.

Comment: @TC yes, you're right, but I haven't said anything about `lvalue`s. Please feel free to edit my answer or add more comments if you think it needs some clarification

Answer (score 0):

It is correct.

```
 display(a=10); //It assigns 10 to a and 10 is passed as the parameter to function.
```